# Почему выводится мусор

Tags: c, функции, указатели, buffer

Почему выводится мусор, хотя я проверил, адреса передаются правильно и я пробовал выводить в main'е строки (T_String.*Pointer) и всё выдаёт правильно, а вот в функции не правильно?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <mem.h>

#define MAX_BUFFER 255

typedef struct{
    int *pointer;
    int length;
} T_String;

int equals_len(T_String *a,int n){
    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; ++j) {
            if(a[i].length==a[j].length){
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}

//сортировка вставками
void InsertionSort(T_String *a,int n)
{
    T_String b;
    int j;

    for (int i = 1; i < n; i++)
    {
        b = a[i];
        j = i - 1;
        while(j >= 0 && a[j].length > b.length)
        {
            a[j+1] = a[j];
            j = j - 1;
        }
        a[j+1] = b;
    }
}

int word_distantion(T_String *a, T_String *b){
    int d=0;

    for (int i = 0; i < a->length; ++i) {
        printf("%s", a->pointer[i]); //Выводится какой-то мусор
    }

    //for (int i = 0; (i < a.length) && (i < b.length); ++i) {

        //printf("%s and %s = %i\n",a.pointer[i],b.pointer[i],a.pointer[i]!=b.pointer[i]);
        //if(a.pointer[i]!=b.pointer[i]){
           // d++;
        //}
    //}
}

int main() {
    signed char buffer[MAX_BUFFER];
    int n;
    T_String *strings;
    printf("Введите кол-во слов: ");
    scanf("%i",&n);
    strings = malloc(n * sizeof(T_String));

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        scanf("%s",buffer);
        strings[i].pointer = malloc(strlen(buffer) * sizeof(char));
        strcpy(strings[i].pointer,buffer);
        strings[i].length = strlen(buffer);
    }

    if(!equals_len(strings,n)){
        //InsertionSort(strings,n);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < n-1; ++i) {
        for (int j = i+1; j < n; ++j) {
            if(word_distantion(&(strings[i]), &(strings[j]))>0){
                //printf("%s and %s = %i\n",a[i].pointer,a[j].pointer,word_distantion(a[i],a[j]));
            }
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `%s` вывод строку, а Вы им пытаетесь вывести символ. Более того, тип указателя - `int*` - а это очень странно.

Comment: `strings[i].pointer = malloc(strlen(buffer) * sizeof(char))` и затем `strcpy(strings[i].pointer,buffer)` - типичная ошибка. Не выделена память для нулевого терминатора.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас может быть несколько причин. Для начала избавимся от очевидного.

Ну-с, по порядку :

- Заголовочного файла `mem.h` не существует в стандартной библиотеке языка "C". Для манипуляций со "строками" есть `string.h`'
- Я очень сомневаюсь, что вы хотели реализовать в вашей структуре указатель на тип `int`. В вашем случае, вы работаете со строками, поэтому нужно заменить `int* pointer;` на `char* pointer;`
- Память кто будет освобождать? :) Создайте функции, освобождающие память каждой строки в структуре и сам массив структур.

### О самой проблеме:

Не знаю, какой у вас компилятор, но на моём `gcc` в указанном вами месте вообще возникает "segmentation fault". И правильно, ведь вы просите вывести *строку* из какого-то `int*`- элемента , не находите странным?

Если вы хотите вывести символ из какого-то типа данных, то:

1. Используйте указатель на маркер `%c` (у вас же `%s`, что не соответствует логике поочерёдного вывода символа одной строки).
2. Используйте в правом аргументе `printf` тип `char`, либо выбирайте определенный символ из типа `char*`, но у вас `int*`, поэтому и проблема (есть и другие опции, но для данной ситуации это всё, что вам нужно знать).

Иначе, говоря `%s` замените на `%c`, а определение структуры поменяйте сл. образом :

```
/*2^n размер гораздо лучше для процессора*/
#define MAX_BUFFER_LENGTH 256 

typedef struct{
    /*не массив чисел, а массив символов, т.е. строка*/
    char* pointer; 
    int length;
} String_t; 
/*такое имя больше подходит 
для псевдонима структуры, но это ваше право*/
```

**P.S** : для этого вопроса не обязательно было знать, как вы сортируете и читаете данные, поэтому в сл. раз не тратьте своё время и время других, показывая самое основное (псевдоним и ваш вывод, который не работает), чтобы мы разбирались не во всём вашем коде, а только в ключевой его части.

Comment: Хорошо, в следующий раз буду оставлять только основное, СПАСИБО )

Comment: Вот сижу и думаю, действительно, а на кой чёрт я вместо `char* pointer` написал `int* pointer`

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, насколько я понял, вы уже сами поняли, в чём проблема? :)

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy, со всеми бывает. Главное, что исправили :P

Comment: да что-то по невнимательности рачить стал

Comment: @alex-rudenkiy "не вы первый, не вы последний" :D